# Passing data between JSP pages

Tags: jsp

I would like to pass the ${ad} variable from within

```
<c:forEach var="ad" items="${requestScope.advertisements}">
```

to another JSP page. How can I do that? This is a bean object, so simple form will not work.

Answer (score 0):

if the $ad is the variable of your bean and the bean is session scoped then you can easily access the variable anyplace by #{userBean.myvar} where myvar will be your ad , and if you need this variable in another bean you can use bean injection for that.

Comment: It's an element of a request scoped map, so unfortunately it won't be so easy.